# Join elements of array into a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am pretty new on Javascript and am little confused with this conversion.

```
var string = ['a','b','c'];
```

to

```
'a','b','c'
```

Comment: if I may, covert to what?

Comment: What are you converting to?

Comment: ['a','b','c'].join()

Comment: It simple returns like this a,b,c But i want with the quotes 'a','b','c'

Comment: `JSON.stringify(["a","b","c"]).replace(/^\[|\]$/g,"");` Give double quotes, but a fun answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join your elements with `','` and add `'` before and after them:

```
var string = ['a','b','c'];
var result;

if(string.length > 0){ // additional condition to avoid ''
    result = "'" + string.join("','") + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var result = "'"+['a','b','c','d','e'].join("','")+"'";
console.log(result);
```